# Many to Many Relationship Keys

Tags: entity-framework

I have 2 entity objects (table1 and table3) with a many to many relationship via an intermediary table (table2) containing only the 2 PK/FK keys.

With the relationship manager I can view the end points of the relationship (table1 and table3) but I need to know the name of "table2" and the names of the PK/FK fields in table2.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need the name of the relationship table?

Answer (score 0):

What DBMS are you using? If mysql, do a "SHOW TABLES" to get the tables listed, and then "DESCRIBE *TABLENAME*" to list the fields in *TABLENAME*

Comment: The underlying system is MS SQL 2005.
Just to be clear, I need to get the name of the table and the composite key names from the Entity Framework object, not from the database.